# evenly distribute li items

Tags: html, css

hope this is self explanatory:

HTML:

```
<ul class="steps">
<li class="step1 first">
    <div class="icon basket"></div>
    1.Warenkorb
</li>
<li class="step2">
    <div class="icon registration"></div>
    2.Adresse
</li>
<li class="step3">
    <div class="icon payment"></div>
    3.Zahlungsart
</li>
<li class="step4">
    <div class="icon order"></div>
    4.Bestätigen
</li>
<li class="step5 last">
    <div class="icon thankyou last"></div>
    5.Danke
</li>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.steps {
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
background:url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_slice.png) repeat-x;
 }

 .steps li {
width:20%;
float:left;

}

.steps li .icon {
background:url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png) no-repeat;
height:44px;
width:44px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HYYwn/1/

how can i achieve that the distances between the bubbles are all the same and the bubble of step5 is on the far right? i am constraint to have 5 different li's and to use % so it stays responsive.

can't get around this myself at the moment playing with it for a while already!

EDIT:

the result should look like this

```
 O--O--O--O--O
```

and not like

```
--O--O--O--O--O
```

or

```
O--O--O--O--O--
```

or

```
--O--O--O--O--O--
```

Comment: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/LKWwy/) what you want? (only the bubbles, text can be looked upon if the bubble positioning is ok).

Comment: that just flipped the problem from the last bubble to the first! it should look like O-O-O-O-O, mine looks like O-O-O-O-O- yours -O-O-O-O-O

Comment: When you say, 'on the far right', do you mean that you want the bubble against the edge? Or something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MSnVn/1/

Comment: I thought on similar lines, thats why I posted as a comment than a solution. Let me try again :)

Comment: both sides should end with a bubble against the edge no lines.

Comment: Can your markup be modified or should it remain untouched?

Comment: it can be modified i just need a unsorted list with 5 list items

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/HYYwn/6/ It is not exactly at the right, but it's close.

Comment: yeah but it also breaks for mobile devices :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using `text-align: justify`.

The advantage of this approach is that the circle/bubble motifs are evenly spaced and you can also control the justification of the labels beneath then.

You first need to wrap the labels in a container, I used a `<p>` tag, and add a terminating `<li>` element, equivalent to the clearing element.

```
<ul class="steps">
    <li class="step1 first">
        <div class="icon basket"></div>
        <p>1.Warenkorb</p>
    </li>
    <li class="step2">
        <div class="icon registration"></div>
        <p>2.Adresse</p>
    </li>
    <li class="step3">
        <div class="icon payment"></div>
        <p>3.Zahlungsart</p>
    </li>
    <li class="step4">
        <div class="icon order"></div>
        <p>4.Bestätigen</p>
    </li>
    <li class="step5 last">
        <div class="icon thankyou last"></div>
        <p>5.Danke</p>
    </li>
    <li class="filler"></li>
</ul>
```

For the **CSS**:

```
.steps {
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_slice.png) repeat-x;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 0;
}
.steps li {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.steps li .icon {
    background:url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png) top center no-repeat;
    height:44px;
    width:44px;
}
.steps li p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    left: -22px;
    margin: 0;
}
.steps li.first p {
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
}
.steps li.last p {
    text-align: right;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
.steps li.filler {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[See demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JByr6/)

First, I used `text-align: justify` on the parent container to evenly distribute the `li` elements which are inline-blocks that shrink to fit the square `.icon` elements.

The `.filler` line forces a new 100% width line that allows the text-justify to work.  I set the `vertical-align: top` (and `line-height: 0` in the parent) to get rid of a orphan with space that is created by the filler element.

I then take the labels out of the flow using absolute positioning, and the adjust the text-alignment for the first and last list items and position them using a negative margin to center the labels.

The one limitation is that there the width is specified for the labels, so you should add a min-width to the parent container as you see fit.

You have plenty of room here to adjust things as needed.

Comment: Superb solution! Elegant in its simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

See [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/HYYwn/11/)

I'm using the `calc` function for the width of the 4 first `li`s.

this is working like this.

the 4 first will look like `O------` and the 5'th will look like `O`.

```
width: calc((100% - 44px)/4);
```

Explanation:  the fifth `li` takes exactly 44px, so the 4 first `li`s divide the rest between them equally.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
ul{
    text-align: justify;
}

ul::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.steps {
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
background:url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_slice.png) repeat-x;
 }

 .steps li {
width:20%;
float:left;
left: 200px;
right: 200px;
}

.steps li .icon {
background:url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png) no-repeat;
height:44px;
width:44px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HYYwn/2/

Comment: this has the same output as the OP's.

Comment: Did you save your fiddle to the most recent version?

Comment: i dont see any difference!?

Comment: you can make the right and left greater, and see if it makes the difference you want it too, just trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I loved this question! Real brain teaser...

Here's what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/HYYwn/10/

I've simplified the HTML and swapped your icon `<div />` for `<img />`s because these are easier to maintain the square ratio that's required. Can be done with a `<div />` but we need to use a bit of JS to make it responsive.

### [Simplified] HTML

```
<div class="steps">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img  src="http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img  src="http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img  src="http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img  src="http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img  src="http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.steps * {
    position: relative;
}
.steps {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_slice.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 50%;
}
.steps ul {
    width: 119%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.steps li {
    width: 20%;   /* 1/5 of ul.width */
    float: left;
}
.steps img {
    width: 20%;   /* 1/5 of li.width */
    height: auto; /* Always "square" */
}
```

**Note:** there's a magic number being used here... **119%**.
I can't tell you why that works, but it does. Hopefully someone smarter than me can explain the algebra behind that value (note that if we change the `<img />` width then we must change this value).

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this with `:before` and it works quite nicely, the only thing that you might be worried about is `last-child` but you can add a `.last-child` class to the last item that will make it cross browser.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F2Kh6/**

**CSS**

```
li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

li .icon{
    background: url('http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

li:last-child:before{
    display: none;
}

li:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    background: url('http://tnsdev.cloudapp.net/dev/steps_slice.png') repeat-x;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

So we just but the steps slice in the `:before` and hide the `:before` on the `:last-child`